# PHP detecting a specific non alphanumeric UTF8 / Unicode charter in a string

Tags: php, unicode-string

I'm looping through an array of items from a 3rd party source I need to determine my actions based on a string starting with one of three characters.

✅❌⚠

Which I believe are the following in unicode

u+2705 ✅ ,  u+274E ❌ , u+26A0 ⚠

If I try something like this to find one of the specific characters:

```
if (strpos("\u{274C}", $event->getSummary()) == true) {
   echo "<h1>FOUND! \u{274C} :</h1>";
}
```

It never matches.
I have found a more generalised method which finds *any* non standard alpha numeric characters - but I need to act on each particular 'symbol' and I'm not sure how to match those based on what I have found the encoding to be.

```
 if(preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7e]/', $event->getSummary())){
     echo 'Found something';
            
 }
```

Comment: PHP Strings are byte streams, you should stick to a single method of encoding and stick to it. UTF-8 is the closest, PHP supported encoding, to Unicode so I'd suggest using that.

Comment: I didn't encode these strings - they are part of a API rest response. Which is part of why I don't know how to match them I guess.